# How to access restrict a Http Azure Function from another

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a Http trigged Azure Function App on resource group A, and I need to invoke this one from another Azure Function app on a resource group B.

I've tried Networking > Access Restrictions

I got the Azure Function ( resource group B) ip address from Settings > Properties

Back on the first Azure Function ( resource group A) and set this ip address on Access Restrictions as allowed

But I'm facing 403 Forbidden warning

*[Information]   StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Ip Forbidden', Version: 1.1*

Have anyone a idea how can I restrict the first AF?

Comment: Just a thought and to get you thinking a little differently, maybe don’t invoke it via a HTTP trigger. What if you used a queue trigger instead? Or does it need to be HTTP for other external calls? Given you want to secure/ restrict it, I was thinking not.

Comment: it was my first sugestion, but they want a http trigged function @Skin

Comment: Maybe via AD auth then?

Comment: Maybe you used the inbound IP address instead of the outbound IP adresses? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal#find-outbound-ip-addresses

Answer (score 0):

Azure Function outbound can use multiple ips.

You can get that list in Settings > Properties.

[image]

You must whitelist at least the Outbound IP addresses list

If you plan to scale your function app, you must whitelist the Additional Outbound IP Addresses

Another solution is to use a Service tag in the Access Restrictions of the Function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview

The service tag for this scenario is **AppService**. This service can be regional, so you may use **AppService.your-region**

None of this solution will ensure that only function B can call function A. To have a single public IP to whitelist, you should use a Nat Gateway, to ensure all outbound traffic use the same public IP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-nat-gateway

(the documentation is not up to date, a premium plan is no longer required)